# Specific issue with Unfortunately AppName has stopped - NullPointerException

Tags: android, cordova, urbanairship.com

I am having issues with my PhoneGap application that has Urban Airship push notifications running. Everything works fine except when closing the app using Android's native task killer (swiping the app off). When the phone is left idle for 30 seconds to a minute I get the error, "Unfortunately, [app] has stopped". I was viewing LogCat and when this error occured I got these errors:

```
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/EmbeddedLogger(595): App crashed! Process: com.appname.pacakagename
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/EmbeddedLogger(595): App crashed! Package: com.appname.pacakagename v1 (1.1.2)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2909)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:162)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at com.urbanairship.Preferences.migratePreferencesFromFileToDb(Preferences.java:173)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at com.urbanairship.analytics.AnalyticsPreferences.<init>(AnalyticsPreferences.java:32)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService.<clinit>(EventService.java:58)
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    ... 13 more
03-04 10:16:30.430: W/asset(595): Copying FileAsset 0x7860b3b0 (zip:/data/app/com.appname.pacakagename-2.apk:/resources.arsc) to buffer size 200924 to make it aligned.
03-04 10:16:30.430: E/EmbeddedLogger(595): Application Label: appname
```

So from this I can see these lines:

```
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 10:16:30.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10257):    at com.urbanairship.Preferences.migratePreferencesFromFileToDb(Preferences.java:173)
```

I wasn't sure where to look to debug that error, I ran this:

```
find ./ -type f -name *Preferences*
```

But I couldn't find any file called Preferences.java.

The plugin this is referring to is:

https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push

The Android src is here:

https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push/tree/master/src/android

Comment: are you running this in main thread?

Comment: Rahul, I am not sure. I just installed the PhoneGap plugin, I guess as it is a push notification service that it is running as a background process.

Comment: the simple way to check is ...have you given any runOnUiThread kind of  method? if not then you are running on main thread and in that condition only you will get FATAL exception.

Comment: I have done a search for runOnUiThread and can see that this is used for Cordova library, but not for the Urban Airship plugin.

Comment: oh.. then try one thing ...where ever you are calling Urban Airship.. call it inside uithread and then see whether it makes any difference or not..

Comment: I can't find where Urban Airship may be called. I searched for `com.urbanairship` in my project directory but I couldn't find anything. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Preferences.java created by you?

Comment: No, where I am using PhoneGap I haven't touched any Java files... just installed plugins.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48949/discussion-between-ian-jamieson-and-rahul)

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by upgrading to the latest version of the Urban Airship plugin and my version of PhoneGap.